# Identify type of equation or how to solve

Tags: numerical-methods, physics, kinematics

I have a bit of a basic question as I can't recall exactly what it is. I have the function outlined below and I am unsure what type of equation it is or how to solve it, I just know that it requires a numerical methods to solve. Help with either would be appreciated.

The function is a rearranging of the position function.

$$K = -Acos(\omega t) - Bsin(\omega t_0)t$$

Where K is some known value, A and B are constants, $t_0$ is the initial time which is known and the function variable to solve for is $t$

Thanks.

Comment: How big $t$ do you expect?

Comment: Could be any value above 0, but typically about $1*10^{-14}$ or thereabout depending on the material

Comment: If the frequency is also small $(\omega t \approx 0)$, you can use $\cos(\omega t) \approx 1$ to get a linear equation.

Comment: Frequency is extremely high so that would not be the case here. For my current case, on the order of $10^{12}$. The lowest I've considered is on the order of $10^{3}$

Comment: If $t \approx 10^{-14}$ and $\omega \approx 10^{12}$, then $\omega t \approx 10^{12-14}=10^{-2}$. Are you sure about the numbers?

Comment: Yep, these were the values (for $\omega$ and $t$) that I was told to expect.

Comment: Then I think that $\cos(\omega t) \approx 1$ is a good approximation with $\omega t \approx 10^{-2}$: $t \approx -\frac{A+K}{B\sin(\omega t_0)}$. But you can use $\cos(\omega t) \approx 1- \frac{(\omega t)^2}{2}$ to get an even better approximation.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will give that a shot and see if it converges for most of my cases.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the zero of function
$$f(t)=K+A\cos(\omega t) + B\sin(\omega t_0)\,t$$ I would prefer to let $x=\omega t$ and work $$f(x)=K+A\cos(x)+\frac B \omega \sin(\omega t_0)\,x$$ Let $C=\frac B \omega \sin(\omega t_0)$ to make the equation
$$f(x)=K+A\cos(x)+Cx$$ If $x$ is supposed to be small, expanding as Taylor series you should get
$$f(x)=(A+K)+C x-\frac{A x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ from which an approximation
$$x_{est}=\frac{\sqrt{ 2A^2+2 A K+C^2}+C}{A}$$ and, since $C$ is probably very large, approximate again
$$x_{est}=\frac{2 C}{A}+O\left(\frac{1}{C^2}\right)$$ Use Newton method to polish the root.